# Error Testing Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to use factory girl to test my create action in rails. I keep getting:

```
"Event.count" didn't change by 1.
<2> expected but was
<1>.
```

When I run my tests. I don't believe I've done anything to change my tests or the controller:

My test looks like this:

```
test "should get create" do
    assert_difference('Event.count') do
      post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:event)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:event)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

I've also tried using `FactoryGirl.build(:event)` as well. I've used that previously, and I think that is the right the method to be using from what I've read.

Here is my factory:

```
   factory :event do
        name 'First Event'
        street '123 street'
        city 'Chicago'
        state 'IL'
        date '1/12/2012'
      end
```

Here is my controller action

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
    @event.save
end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm curious if its error'ing out because of model validations, thus not saving. Do you have an exception handler to check errors? If not, you could easily `debugger` the line before the create,and see if your instance variable validates properly.

Comment: I have no validations in place on the event model. That was my first thought too.

Comment: What if you through a debugger write after you instantiate `@event`. Then try to manually save it. Does the object create?

Comment: I figured it out thanks to your suggestion. I had a before_filter that was preventing the save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to scope out your error, try throwing a `debugger` in your action :

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  debugger
  @event.save
end
```

See if you manally resolve an @event.save and what errors might prevent that. :D